# Why the Second Javascript Function returns NaN?

Tags: javascript

This one works:

```js
function fact(n) {
  return n > 1 ? n * fact(n - 1) : n;
}

console.log(fact(4)) // Returns 24
```

This returns `NaN`:

```js
function fact(n) {
  return n > 1 ? n * fact(n - 1) : `Factorial is : ${n}`;
}

console.log(fact(4)) // Returns NaN
```

Why the second function returns `NaN`?

Comment: Because you cannot multiply a number with `"Factorial is : 1"`

Comment: you are returning a string for your basecase.

Comment: But n is the final input in the second condition.

Comment: Just do the steps for `n === 2` by hand. `fact(2)` -> `2 * fact(1)` -> `2 * "Factorial is : 1"` - This cannot work -> `NaN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your second function pon the second line:

`Factorial is : ${n}`

here ( backtick) means Template literals. Template literals can contain placeholders to add a variable inside a string. so basically `` contains a string.

when you  used

```
`return n > 1 ? n * fact(n - 1) : `Factorial is : ${n}`;
```

at the end of the recursive function , you are returning **STRING** .

then the string is trying to multiply with a number:   **number * string**

so the function is returning: **NaN**

Answer (score 3):

Your fact function is recursive one. This means that when your function reaches its end, first condition returns string and next function call is trying to multiply string with number -> hence, NaN